How to extract temperature data form a file with an extension .ravi in python
I have a *.ravi file generated from optris IR camera. I'm able to extract frames from ravi file. but i can not find the solution how to get temperature from that. Suggest me on how to extract temperature data in python.
I have tried av2 python library which only gives frames. But i need temperature in each frame at a specified location

Have you read this

Here you can find OpenCV example - LINK

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
